# How to match and plot corresponding points in two data frames when each is different size?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with the same columns and date indices:

df1:

```
Date        T.TO AS.TO NTR.TO ... R.TO
2016-03-03  0.1  0.02  0.04       0.02
2016-03-04  0.09 0.01  0.02       0.02
2016-03-05  0.1  0.02  0.04       0.02
...
2019-03-03  0.09 0.01  0.02       0.02
```

[816 rows x 35 columns]

df2:

```
Date        T.TO AS.TO NTR.TO ... R.TO
2016-03-03  0.01  0.32  0.04       0.02
2016-03-04  0.81  0.21  0.02       0.02
2016-03-05  0.01  0.12  0.04       0.02
...
2019-03-03  0.89  0.11  0.12       0.72
```

[825 rows x 35 columns]

I want to plot all the matching points of the two dataframes on a chart like the first point would correspond to `2016-03-03, T.TO (0.1, 0.01)`. Another point would correspond to `2016-03-03, AS.TO (0.02, 0.32)` and so on giving me a large number of points. I will then use these to find a line of best fit.

I know how to find the best fit line but I am having difficulty plotting these points directly.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
plt.scatter(df1.set_index.stack(), df2.set_index.stack())
```

but that doesn't work because the dataframes are different sizes so then I tried merging the two:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1.stack(), df2.stack(), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
```

But I get the error that unnamed series cannot be merged.

Is there a way to create a new dataframe that only retains values in df2 based on dates present in df1?

Comment: rename the series: `s1=df1.stack(); s1.name='s1'`

Comment: should be `plt.scatter(new_df['s1'], new_df['s2'])`

Comment: What is on X-Y axis on your plot?